# How to find unused classes in my HTML?

Tags: html, css, optimization

There are lots of tools for finding unused CSS rules in stylesheets, such as [Chrome Audits](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#audits) and the [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) add-on for Firefox (unfortunately not compatible with Firefox Quantum).

But what about the other way around?

How do I find classes that are in my HTML, that do not exist in my stylesheets?

Comment: Note that you may have "unused" classes in your HTML so that Javascript can access elements. They aren't just for styling.

Comment: Although this question is currently tagged "optimization", such a tool would also be useful for people who are copying HTML from one project to another, and need to check what styling needs to be copied as well.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I see you added a bounty; the following isn't really enough for an answer but it might be pretty easy to script in C#. Get a list of class names used in html with HtmlAgilityPack, and then parse the css files with ExCSS and cross reference. Even automatically exporting new files containing only the required CSS would be pretty simple.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This may be helpful: https://code.google.com/p/find-unused-classes/ . According to the description:

> It shows classes that exist in css selectors and do not exist on html page and like-verse.

As Jim said, be warned that some classes may be unused by your stylesheets but still used in JavaScript.

Comment: The project started on Jul 12, 2001 and had its last commit on [Jul 28 2011](https://code.google.com/archive/p/find-unused-classes/source/default/commits)

Answer (score 8):

HTML Inspector from https://github.com/philipwalton/html-inspector has this as one of its features:

> - **Unused Classes**: Sometimes you'll remove a CSS rule from your stylesheet but forget to remove the class from the HTML. The "unused-classes" rule compares all the class selectors in the CSS to the classes in the HTML and reports any that aren't being used.
>
>   Classes that are in the HTML as JavaScript hooks can be ignored via a whitelist. By default, any class prefixed with `js-`, `language-`, or `supports-` is whitelisted. More information on the rationale behind this rule can be found [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/css-architecture/).

[In its FAQ you will find a bookmarklet](https://github.com/philipwalton/html-inspector/blob/master/FAQs.md#is-there-a-browser-extension-or-bookmarklet-for-html-inspector).

Or add it via a script tag:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html-inspector/0.8.2/html-inspector.js"></script>
```

And run with this snippet:

```
HTMLInspector.inspect(["unused-classes"]);
```

[A comment by Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800008/how-to-find-unused-classes-in-my-html#comment83976986_46001154) points out that this project is no longer maintained (last commit December 2017). Fortunately it still seems to be functional (tested June 2019).

There is also [grunt-unclassify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-unclassify) but that project seems dead (last commit December 2014).

Comment: This project looks promising, but it currently has a message saying "NOTE: I no longer have time to maintain this project, respond to issues, or address PRs. If anyone else would like to take over as a maintainer, please contact me."

Comment: @AndrewGrimm What a bummer. On a side note, let me guess, you are in the process of switching from Bootstrap 3 to 4?

Comment: no, moving react components from one project to another project.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Ah OK, this what I needed it for anyway and in the end I simply did a diff of the used CSS classes and then wrote a simple script to detect usage of the old classes. In the case of BS4 there is hope that possible the next version of Bootlint will have detection of the old classes: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint

Answer (score 7):

This is a partial answer on how to get the class names in html

```
var classesEvery = [];
var elementsEvery = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elementsEvery.length; i++) {
  var classes = elementsEvery[i].className.toString().split(/\s+/);
  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var thisClass = classes[j];
    if (thisClass && classesEvery.indexOf(thisClass) === -1)
      classesEvery.push(thisClass);
  }
}
```

One can get the Class names in the html file using this Javascript code. 
For getting all classes used in CSS, try [list-selectors](https://github.com/davidtheclark/list-selectors). Still thinking on how to get class names used in Javascript angularJS.
Added a working snippet with random HTML classes to test the js.

```js
var classesEvery = [];
var elementsEvery = document.querySelectorAll('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elementsEvery.length; i++) {
  var classes = elementsEvery[i].className.toString().split(/\s+/);
  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var thisClass = classes[j];
    if (thisClass && classesEvery.indexOf(thisClass) === -1)
      classesEvery.push(thisClass);
  }
}
console.log(classesEvery);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Some random HTML code. -->
<div ng-controller="HomeController" class="container hidden">

  <span>Simple Notifications:</span>
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="simple()">Simple notification</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-warning" href ng-click="warning()">Warning notification</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-success" href ng-click="success()">Success notification</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-danger" href ng-click="error()">Error notification</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-grimace" href ng-click="wait()">Wait notification</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="pop()">Link to other page</button></div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <span>Addding Option from Script:</span>
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <Span>With CLose button</span>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="close()">Close Button </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <Span>Fade after 1 Sec</span>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="timeout()">Html notification</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <hr/>
  <span>Custom Notification and Body output type:</span>
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="Custom_temp()">Custom template</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="trusted_html()">Trusted HTML</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="default_temp()">Default Template</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary" href ng-click="file_custom_temp()">Including file from Folder</button></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
    <div class="Custom_temp_html">
      <p>Notice, custom temlate is not in the list</p>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this eliminate class names which have some sort of styling, or does it list all class names?

Comment: All style names, thats why you should look into your JS application as well as CSS. Also, some apps add classes through JS. That's why this problem of finding "unused" classes is hard.

Comment: Look into https://github.com/davidtheclark/list-selectors to get all class names in CSS.

Comment: @Harsha Well, you can look at a DOM snapshot (which you can automate using PhantomJS) which might be already quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

The tool `grunt-unclassify` looks promising too, altough its use doesn't seem straightforward:

https://medium.com/@mariusc23/remove-unused-css-classes-in-html-bbb856da8bdf#.55u0uokfb

Comment: This answer ought to mention what the name of the tool is - as it is, it's fairly much a "link only answer".

Comment: In a later answer, phk says that grunt-unclassify seems to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

When passed an HTMLElement, the following code outputs unused classes and ids:

```
function unused(e) {
  const s0 = JSON.stringify(window.getComputedStyle(e));
  const c = Array.from(e.classList.values());
  if (c.length !== 0) {
    c.forEach(cc => {
      e.classList.remove(cc);
      const s = JSON.stringify(window.getComputedStyle(e));
      if (s0 === s) {
        console.log(`class ${cc} is unused`);
      }
      e.classList.add(cc);
    });
  }
  const id = e.id;
  if (id) {
    e.removeAttribute("id");
    const s = JSON.stringify(window.getComputedStyle(e));
    if (s0 === s) {
      console.log(`id ${id} is unused`);
    }
    e.id = id;
  }
}
```

It works by extracting the style of the element via `window.getComputedStyle()`, and then removing classes one by one and checking to see if the style is still the same.

(If you want a version of the HTML with the extraneous classes and ids removed, then modify the code to only re-add the classes if they affected styling, call the function recursively on all child nodes, and then use [`XMLSerializer. serializeToString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) to serialize the DOM.)

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/detect-unused-classes-in-html/

> I saw Robert Kieffer post a Gist the other day with an interesting solution. The idea is to load up document.styleSheets and find all the rules (the ones that are classes). Then, use a MutationObserver to watch the DOM for all HTML, and check the classList of each node to see if it matches any from any stylesheet. If the HTML has a class not found in a stylesheet, report it.

https://gist.github.com/broofa/7e95aad7ea0f34655428cda9868e7fa3

also published as a npm package: https://github.com/broofa/checkcss