# How to track a used CSS class in HTML that doesn't exist in the CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML file that uses multiple classes in CSS file. Is there a way to quickly track classes that don't exist in the CSS file? I need to determine them to add them to the CSS file.

Comment: You'll need to provide code examples. Throw together a simple use case in a jsfiddle to better explain yourself.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17800008/2126792

Comment: What about looking for `style` sections in your HTML.

Comment: Take a look at this cool tool: http://robertnyman.com/inline-code-finder/