# How can I identify which classes and id are been used in a html document?

Tags: html, css, class

Im trying to remove unused classes and id's in my site. Is there a function that I can use in the browser's JavaScript console (or other methods) to filter out the used/unused classes and elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would know whether a class was used or not - it could be added to an element by JS at some time during run time for example using parameters passed to a function.

Comment: Unused classes compared to what list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find unused classes in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800008/how-to-find-unused-classes-in-my-html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```js
let classList = ["class1","class2","class3","class4","class5"];

classList.forEach(cl=>checkClasses(cl));

function checkClasses(classToCheck) {
  if(document.querySelector('.'+classToCheck)){
    console.log(classToCheck+' is being used');
  }else {
    console.log(classToCheck+' is not being used');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
<div class="class4"></div>
<div class="class5"></div>
```